# two parameters for namedQuery restful webservice

Tags: java, rest, web-services

i"ve restful webservices generated from netbeans wizard. there is get method for retrieve data from database based on id(Select * From example Where id=someId) and return single result.

i've tried different criteria, let's say name which will be return more than one result and i get this error :

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to web.Barang

can somebody tell me how to fix this, any help will be very appreciated

this is my files :

my NamedQuery(barang.java)

> @NamedQuery(name = "Barang.cariId", query = "SELECT b FROM Barang b
>   WHERE b.postCategoryId = :postCategoryId AND b.status ='tersedia'")

my function (AbstractFacade.java)

```
public T cariId(Integer postCategoryId) {
  return  (T) getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Barang.cariId").setParameter("postCategoryId", postCategoryId).getResultList().toString();
}
```

my GET method (barangfacadeRest.java)

```
@GET
@Path("cariId/{postCategoryId}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Barang cariId(@PathParam("postCategoryId") int postCategoryId) {
   return super.cariId(postCategoryId);
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `toString` call what do you get?

Comment: hi, thx for replying. the result is still the same. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If `T` is a generic type parameter, I think something is missing. In addition to that it doesn't make any sense to define this method generic because your query can only return objects of type `Barang`. So I would rewrite it as follows:

```
public Barang cariId(Integer postCategoryId {
    TypedQuery<Barang> q =  em.createNamedQuery("Barang.cariId", Barang.class);
    q.setParameter("postCategoryId", postCategoryId);
    List<Barang> result = q.getResultList();
    if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
        return result.get(0);
     }
    return null;
}
```

If other things are correct, this should remove the `ClassCastException` exception.

Comment: thank you in advance.
but i still get error in the code.
here my sc :
https://ibb.co/dxBzBG

i hope you want to help me, i had post my question to numerous forums and no one give answer. only you my last hope.
once again, thank you very much

Comment: Mr.ujulu
thanks for helping me, my code works now

from my deepest heart, thank you very much
may god always bless you and family